# PhpStorm Started Recognising .php Extension as Plain Text

Tags: php, phpstorm

Everything was working fine until now, and all the files I was creating as `.php` was being converted to `.php` file with detecting, coloring and auto-correcting open. I used to create files as created I `User.php` instead of `User.

**PhpStorm randomly started recognising `.php` extension as plain text and without extension as php file.**

However, now something happened and it is shown as (see Profile is not detected as`php` file):

[image]
and is shown as a plain text file:

[image]

When I remove the `.php`, it gets detected:

[image]

And then it gets detected as `PHP` file [image: enter image description here], but the extension is wrong. [4]], but then it doesn't show the extension in the Finder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.. Settings > File Types > Check under PHP and Text and delete Profile